# How to get group matches of regular expressions in CMake?

Tags: regex, cmake

Let's look at the following illustrative example.

```
set(TEXT "ab,cc,df,gg")
string(REGEX MATCHALL "((.)\\2)" RESULT "${TEXT}")
message("Result: ${RESULT}")  

# Expected:  Result: cc;gg
# Actual:    Result:
```

Compare the expected result on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nT9zY3).

Does anyone know how to retrieve match group 1 correctly in the above example? Is this possible at all with CMake?

I couldn't find much on the limitations of the regular expression processor used by CMake in the web. Who knows more? (There's a little something written about this in [CMake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Which_regular_expressions_are_supported_by_CMake.3F))

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMake's regular expressions are relatively limited. Look at the `static char* regatom (int *flagp)` method in [RegularExpression.cxx](http://www.cmake.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/CMake/Source/kwsys/RegularExpression.cxx?view=co). A `\\`
indicates that the next character is escaped (treated literally). It looks like there are no back-references possible in the CMake regex.

As a work around, you can invoke shell commands using `execute_process`.

```
set(TEXT "ab,cc,df,gg")
message("TEXT: ${TEXT}")

execute_process(
    COMMAND echo ${TEXT}
    COMMAND sed "s/.*\\(\\(.\\)\\2\\).*/\\1/g"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE RESULT OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )

message("RESULT: ${RESULT}")
```

This produces:

```
TEXT: ab,cc,df,gg
RESULT: gg
```

You will have to adjust your regex do produce `cc;gg` from the given string.

Comment: This is however not portable to windows for instance